# how can i define 2x WHERE

Tags: mysql, sql

current query:

```
SELECT * FROM `invoices2` WHERE `status` = 2
```

I need to select status 1 and status 2, how can I do it?

I already tried things like `2 AND 1` or `WHERE 'status' = 2 AND WHERE 'status' = 1`

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need is:

```
WHERE status IN (1, 2)
```

To be clear, this is equivalent to:

```
WHERE status = 1 OR status = 2;
```

You can have very complex expressions in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: This is the best answer for OP's situation, but for the record if you ever need 2 conditions that can't be combined in an `IN` you would do something like `WHERE 'status' = 2 OR 'status' = 1`

Answer (score 1):

You can also do:

```
SELECT * FROM `invoices2` WHERE `status` = 1 OR `status` = 2
```

In single query you always have only one `WHERE` keyword and then you can extend it by adding OR, AND, NOT.

Answer (score 0):

If they are in different rows you need and for more Status values its own extsts

```
SELECT * FROM `invoices2` 
WHERE `status` = 2 AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM `invoices2` WHERE `status` = 1)
```